# Stop behavior open file again after close it?

Tags: 22.10

I have upgrade my ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 ...
But I have ugly behavior.
If I open for example some file (1.txt) and then close it and then try to open other file (2.txt) I have got (1.txt) still open in other tab ... How can I stop this behavior ?!

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this behavior with the information provided on a 22.10 test system. Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1443780/edit) to provide clear, step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Which text editor are you using?

Comment: Test editor ... I have solve it to set gedit as default .... Than you